# Parsing POCO POST response to JSON using Rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, poco-libraries, rapidjson

I am suffering from burnout messing with this backlashes...

I made a POST request in C++ and receive the following string:

```
"{\"results\": [{\"sku\": \"peds-std-us\", \"url\": \"https://d2y247jlvj8usn.cloudfront.net/1/2014.06.12/upload test.xlsx\", \"version\": \"2014.06.12\"}]}"
```

Then I process it like a `rapidjson` document but I get Parse Errors.

```
Document document;
if(document.Parse(results.c_str()).HasParseError()){
    return 1;
}
```

I tried removing the begin and end `""`

like this

`{\"results\": [{\"sku\": \"peds-std-us\", \"url\": \"https://d2y247jlvj8usn.cloudfront.net/1/2014.06.12/upload test.xlsx\", \"version\": \"2014.06.12\"}]}`

Same problem...

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: What happens if you strip the `\ ` characters?  Does it have a parse error then?  Also test the begin and end `"` characters.

Comment: Thanks man, that is what I am currently trying... but using str.replace gives me a crash

Comment: `str.replace` should not cause a crash.

Comment: The problem is that this simply is not JSON. I guess someone added quotes (or is that in fact a C++ string literal?) in order to keep some other piece of software from interpreting the intermediate double quotes as delimiters of the string. In any case, the I believe you should split your problem in finding out how to retrieve proper JSON and finding out how to parse JSON.

Comment: it is a c++ string literal, if you remove the \ and the first and last " you get valid JSON. But its killing me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the JSON fails to being parsed by rapidjson it's because of all the excess backlashes `\` and the first and last double quotes `"`. Thus I remove them as follows.

```
if (*resultsCopy.begin() == '"')
    if (*(resultsCopy.rbegin()) == '"')
        resultsCopy = resultsCopy.substr(1, resultsCopy.length() - 2);
    else
        resultsCopy = resultsCopy.substr(1, resultsCopy.length() - 1);
else if (*(resultsCopy.rbegin()) == '"')
    resultsCopy = resultsCopy.substr(0, resultsCopy.length() - 1);

char chars[] = "\\";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); ++i){
    resultsCopy.erase (std::remove(resultsCopy.begin(), resultsCopy.end(), chars[i]), resultsCopy.end());
}
```

That stuff removes every `\` and the `"` at the beginning and the end.
And now it is a valid JSON

Thanks to @Mooing Duck for this

Here is the clean JSON

`{"results": [{"sku": "peds-std-us", "url": "https://d2y247jlvj8usn.cloudfront.net/1/2014.06.12/upload test.xlsx", "version": "2014.06.12"}]}`

Any advice is welcome